New the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document
I have a problem with my visual studio, in my webApplication (and only in my webApplication) my breakpoints are not reached.
I've just got to this project, I've cloned the repository and my colleague's is working, so it's something specific to the configuration of my visual studio I have version 2022 17.10.1.
it's a C#/Blazor project
I've tried all the solutions found on the internet:

Uninstall VS
Go to "Debug" => Windows => Module (my PDB file isn't in the list of modules, even though it's present in my project next to the .exe file (it doesn't seem to be processing the file)).
Package update
Clean and build
Go to Tools => Option => Debugging => Symbols => load all symbols
I've checked that I'm debugging all the projects in the solution
In short, I've tested a lot of things without finding anything that works (I haven't listed all the solutions here) Do you have any ideas?
They are all in debug


Does this answer your question? How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?

For this issue No symbols have been loaded for this document,please try the following steps:
Please open modules window from Debug > Windows > Modules.
1.If you go to the modules window, do you see your module loaded? If ‘yes’, go to #2, If ‘no’, go to #5
2.Are symbols loaded (check the Symbol Status column)? If ‘yes’ go to #3, if ‘no’ go to #4
3.Are you sure this code is actually getting compiled in? Try adding a print/trace statement there and make sure the code is really running.
4.What is the ‘Symbol Status’? If you right click on the module and look at ‘Symbol Load Information’ does that help?
5.Are you debugging the right process?  Is your code actually running (try adding print statements, include the process id in your output to make sure you are debugging the right process)
For more information, please read the No Symbols have been loaded for this document"
Hope it can help you.

The project in question is not in the list of modules.
list of module
